# Locate element with nbsp

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate an element with nbsp in it.

```
<input name="First&nbsp;name" >


input[@name='First Name']
input[@name='First&nbsp;name']
```

unable to locate the element with the above code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the `nbsp;` and try matching other parts of the string.

```
//input[contains(@name,'First') and contains(@name,'name')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `&nbsp;` with `\u00A0`.

I would suggest a CSS selector

```
input[name='First\u00A0name']
```

but you can also use it in an XPath

```
//input[@name='First\u00A0name']
```

See [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) for more info.